# Question about an equatuon with 2 unknowns?

Tags: linear-algebra

An equation with 2 unknowns has an infinite solutions, but some teachers when they teach the linear system of equations they say consider $2x+3y=0$.

Look you cannot find $x$ and $y$ because if move $+3y$ to the other side you will have $2x=-3y$ and if you move $+2x$ to the other side you will have $3y=-2x$

So can we find $x$ and $y$ by a single  equation of two unknows  or does it has an infinite solutions?

Comment: $3y=-2x$, not $3y=-2$. So your question is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

An equation is a *statement form*, in which 
one or more *placeholders* occur.  Take for example 
$$2x=6,$$
in words: "The double of a number equals six."

If you now replace the placeholder with an object it represents, in our example a number, you'll get a statement, which is as such true or false.  Now we call any substitution for the placeholder which yields a true statement, a *solution* of the equation. Substituting $4$ for $x$ we'll get the statement: "The double of four is six." which is false -- so $4$ is no solution of the equation whereas $3$ is one -- substituting $3$ for $x$ produces a true statement.

In your case we have two placeholder, so pair of numbers -- representable as a point in the coordinate system -- may be a solution.  It reads: "The dum of the double of a number the triple of another number vanishes."  Now the substitution $1$ for the first and $2$ for the second number produces a false statement, hence $(1,2)$ is not a solution whereas $(-3,2)$ is one.

If you write the equation as $y=-\frac23x$ you'll observe that for any substitution of the first number $x$ you'll find a substitution for the second placeholder $y$ which produces a true statement.

The real revolutionary part is due to Descartes, not the "inventor" of coordinate systems, but he discovered that by assigning numbers to points (the coordinates)  geometric objects  are *accessible and thus available by computation*; that was called "Analytical Geometrie".

The solution set of an equation with two placeholders  may be thought as a set of points in the coordinate system, in our case a straight line.  This interpretation of solution sets opens the possibility to *calculate with geometric objects*: not only may we state that -- given another straight line by another equation -- those lines have a common point, but also where its numerical location.

Answer (score 1):

Given equation of a line $Ax+By=C$ we can ask how we can change x and y so that we have new x and y values yet remain, i.e. our new Xs and Ys still satisfy the equation.

$A(x+\Delta x) + B(y+\Delta y) = C$

We know $Ax+By=0$

So the changes in x and y must satisfy $A\Delta x + B\Delta y=0$.

So if we wish to change x by $\Delta x$, then we must have $\Delta y=(-A/B)\Delta x$

Since $\Delta x$ can be an arbitrary real number, we have infinitely many points.